# ServiceStack Swagger NuGet package incomplete

Tags: servicestack, swagger-ui

I'm trying to implement the ServiceStack.Api.Swagger NuGet package in my ServiceStack project, however the /swagger-ui/lib folder is missing both the jquery and handlebars script files indicated in the Index.html.

I was able to mitigate the jquery issue, but the handlebars issue is blocking me. If I just add handlebars-1.1.0.js and reference it in the Index.html, I get:

**Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars than the current runtime**

Am I missing something here in how this package is supposed to work? I expected limited configuration to get it up and running, but I've burned a bunch of hours just trying to get the Index.html to render without throwing script errors.

Comment: thx, we've just added a fix for this and should be available in the next release of SS later today.

Comment: Excellent! I look forward to grabbing it when available. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: FYI, [v3.9.64 has just been deployed to NuGet](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/112445368900682590445). You can join the ServiceStack G+ group to be notified of future releases.

Comment: Works wonderfully. Thank you!